# HTML/CSS Height of div dependent on other divs

Tags: html, css, scroll, height, overflow

I am trying to build a sidebar that takes up 100% of the browser's height. Inside this sidebar, there are two divs that will be changing in size depending on the content inside.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="child-1"></div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffEQd.png (Sorry, I did my best to show an example)

As you can see, The sidebar starts out with `child-2` taking up about 80% of the height (even if its content doesn't fill up the div) and `child-1` only taking up about 20% of the height. However, as `child-1`'s content grows, `child-2` gets smaller. If `child-2`'s content overflows, I will probably be using `overflow-y: scroll` in order to be able to contain its content. Likewise, once `child-1` reaches a `max-height`, I want it to be able to vertically scroll as well.

I can't quite wrap my head around how to do this and handle the changing heights with only CSS. Any help or direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `flex`

```css
body{ margin: 0; }
.sidebar{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child-1{
  background-color: #8989Ef;
}
.child-2{
  background-color: #EF8989;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="child-1">
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content and this content is long</p>
    <p>this is content</p>
    <p>this is content and this content is long</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this through jquery,

you have to get height of each div and then check which div have maximum height. After getting this you have to set this maximum height to each div.

and in CSS you can define maximum height and then overflow-y scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
.sidebar {
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

You would then modify the `flex-basis` of the two child elements to get it exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this CSS

```
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child-1 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 10 0 auto;
  min-height: 20vh;
  max-height: 80vh; // let's say the maximum height of child 1 is 80%
}

.child-2 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

You should aware that flexbox is still pretty new CSS feature, so be caution for the older browsers.